# how to display the latest records in the db. in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

my code to display the latest records in datable in laravel .now it's showing the first in the first. need to display the last data in first

```
if($status == 'pending'){

        $datas = Order::where('status','=','pending')->get();

    }
```

Comment: Just add latest() to your query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you want to get the last record use `latest()->first()`

```
if($status == 'pending'){

    $datas = Order::where('status','=','pending')->latest()->first();

}
```

and if you want to order

```
if($status == 'pending'){

    $datas = Order::where('status','=','pending')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();

}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that by default `->latest()` uses the `created_at` column for sorting, which can be slow if the dataset is large and the column isn't indexed.